# Difference between . and #

Tags: ruby, rspec

In Ruby what is the difference between those two (in code):

- `Class.method`
- `Class#method`

Comment: In code, the first is a method call while the second is a comment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The hash format (Class#method) is not valid ruby, but is used in documentation to describe an instance method.

Class methods are typically documented using a double-colon (Class::method).

You will see examples of both in the ruby docs (e.g. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html)

The dot format is used in code when actually *calling* a class method (Class.method), though I have seen some people (unfortunately) use it interchangeably with either the double-colon or hash in documentation.

Comment: According to the rubocop rspec style guide, you should use a dot when describing a class method: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rspec-style-guide#example-group-naming

Answer (score 43):

It's a naming convention.

- use pound `#method` for instance methods
- use dot `.method` for class methods

See: [How to name RSpec describe blocks for methods](http://grosser.it/2010/06/18/how-to-name-rspec-describe-blocks-for-methods/)

Comment: based on that super terse blog post alone? Shouldnt the documentation format be followed, i.e., `Class::method` for a class method?

Comment: I'm with cdn on this one. The Ruby docs are a canonical source, the blog post is not authoritative, and `.method` is confusing because all methods are called that way. Besides that, class constants are accessed via `::` so it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, the blog post isn't authoritative. But the RuboCop's RSpec Style Guide also says the same thing: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rspec-style-guide#describe-the-methods

Answer (score 5):

`Class#method` is not valid code. It is only used in documentation. method should be an instance method.

`Class.method` or object.method is the actual method belonging to the object. Class is an object too. It is valid code.