# Ruby: Difference between Topic.methods and Topic#methods

Tags: ruby, pry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between . and #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764188/difference-between-and)

Pry gem offers the ability to see all the methods on an object by entering ls -m in the pry console. When I do ls -m on the Topic model, it shows these two types of methods

Topic.methods and Topic#methods. What is the difference?

**Topic.methods**

```
Topic.methods: _create_callbacks  _save_callbacks  _update_callbacks  _validate_callbacks  _validators  after_add_for_posts  after_add_for_posts=  after_add_for_posts?  after_remove_for_posts  after_remove_for_posts=  after_remove_for_posts?  before_add_for_posts  before_add_for_posts=  before_add_for_posts?  before_remove_for_posts  before_remove_for_posts=  before_remove_for_posts?  reflections
```

**Topic#methods**

```
Topic#methods: _one_time_conditions_valid_12?  _one_time_conditions_valid_14?  _one_time_conditions_valid_18?  _one_time_conditions_valid_22?  _one_time_conditions_valid_24?  after_add_for_posts  after_add_for_posts=  after_add_for_posts?  after_remove_for_posts  after_remove_for_posts=  after_remove_for_posts?  autosave_associated_records_for_posts  autosave_associated_records_for_user  before_add_for_posts  before_add_for_posts=  before_add_for_posts?  before_remove_for_posts  before_remove_for_posts=  before_remove_for_posts?  joe  validate_associated_records_for_posts
```

Update

I should note that these two types of methods  only appear after I moved into the first instance of Topic. i.e. cd `Topic.first`

If I only cd into Topic, and do ls -m, I only see

```
Topic.methods
```